Increasing shared memory results in increased response time - Performance Issue

As I mentioned below, the problem was occurring when using Rust +
SQLX.

I started implementing postgresql in a study project, but when I started testing it further I came across the first problem.
Running many requests at the same time did not perform well.
Around 1,000 users per second already had response times that I consider high, compared to mongoDB
Postgres

MongoDB

Of course a query must be considered, but in the case of PostgresQL it is a very basic query, MongoDB accesses two collections sequentially to return the data.
I then decided to configure some parameters to achieve some improvement in this aspect, but I came across another problem.
For any value I put in shared_memory (128MB -> 256MB), the value in response time increases considerably and makes no sense.
It jumps from an average of 3ms to 114ms.
The query in question is this

The users table has 500,000 rows, and cpf is a UNIQUE column
It's strange to see that both times are low, but when you put a timer inside the Rust, the time is very different. 116.48ms
pub async fn get_user_by_cpf(
    cpf: &String,
    pool: PosgressPool,
) -> Result<User, ResponseError> {

    let now = Instant::now();

    let user: User = sqlx::query_as("SELECT * FROM users WHERE cpf=$1")
        .bind(cpf)
        .fetch_one(&pool)
        .await
        .map_err(internal_error)?;

    let elapsed = now.elapsed();

    println!("Elapsed: {:.2?}", elapsed); //116,48ms      

    Ok(user)
}

Connection Pool
use sqlx::{
    postgres::{PgPoolOptions, Postgres},
    Pool,
};

let db_pool: Pool<Postgres> = PgPoolOptions::new()
    .min_connections(1)
    .max_connections(3)
    .connect("postgresql://postgres:password@localhost/payment_system")
    .await
    .unwrap();

This outside of the stress test, just making a single request.
In short, I was getting high response times in a system stress situation. I decide to configure some parameters and by doing so a request that previously took 3ms now takes 116ms
I'm setting up postgresQL instance inside WSL, using native Docker on Ubuntu, this is docker-compose.yml
  postgres_db:
    image: postgres:16.3-alpine
    container_name: postgres
    restart: always
    command:
      - "postgres"
      - "-c"
      - "shared_buffers=256MB"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
    network_mode: host
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

In general, what is happening here, what is the point of increasing shared_memory a little and getting this result, and how can I improve system performance in this situation?
Hardware:
CPU: Ryzen 5 3600 6/12 4GHZ
MEM: 24GB 3200MHZ


How many concurrent connections were you using to make 1000 qps?

do you mean connection pools? I will edit the post showing how I make the connection, but I use a maximum of 3 connections, increasing this did not bring any results.

Your setting for shared_buffers is really really low. And what about the rest of the configuration? For high performance you should optimize the configuration for your situation, a default configuration just gives you a working database cluster, not a fast one

is it trusted authorization through localhost? Or it uses full-blown credentials check up? The latter also adds time, but not quite as much. Databases should be fine-tuned for host they run on.

@Frank Heikens, Indeed, the default configurations are unable to reach the expected level, but where to start? I know that modifying only the shared_buffer is not enough, but when I did that, it strangely increased the response time.

@Swift - Friday Pie, Well, I haven't configured anything regarding that, so I believe it is disabled. It is the default image of PostgreSQL. Additionally, I haven't configured it on the server either.

Now that I seem to see where the problem is coming from, what title should I put on this post, it appears to be a complicated problem with SQLX

For the best performance with such a query in PostgreSQL, use a prepared statement. That will avoid the overhead of re-planning the query every time.

Well, after some time investigating PostgresQL, I discovered that the problem was in Rust + SQLX.
First, with them I was unable to obtain a good result for multiple requests, even changing parameters within the library.
Second, when increasing the shared_buffer, the request becomes incredibly slow for no reason.
As I was getting quick results in pgAdmin, I decided to try another configuration: Node + Express + pg, and that was it. See the results.
const express = require('express');
const { Pool } = require('pg');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const pool = new Pool({
  user: 'postgres',
  host: 'localhost',
  database: 'payment_system',
  password: 'password',
  port: 5432,
  max: 100,
  idleTimeoutMillis: 30000,
  connectionTimeoutMillis: 2000,
});


I also adjusted some parameters in PostgresQL, although they had no effect in Rust + SQLX, in addition to increasing response times.And just like the node, I also set a max connection pool equal to 100
  postgres_db:
    image: postgres:16.3-alpine
    container_name: postgres
    restart: always
    command:
      - "postgres"
      - "-c"
      - "shared_buffers=6GB"
      - "-c"
      - "effective_cache_size=18GB"
      - "-c"
      - "work_mem=16MB"
      - "-c"
      - "maintenance_work_mem=512MB"
      - "-c"
      - "max_connections=200"
      - "-c"
      - "checkpoint_timeout=15min"
      - "-c"
      - "checkpoint_completion_target=0.9"
      - "-c"
      - "wal_buffers=16MB"
      - "-c"
      - "wal_level=replica"
      - "-c"
      - "synchronous_commit=off"
      - "-c"
      - "autovacuum=on"
      - "-c"
      - "autovacuum_max_workers=6"
      - "-c"
      - "autovacuum_naptime=10s"
      - "-c"
      - "autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay=20ms"
      - "-c"
      - "autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit=2000"
      - "-c"
      - "max_worker_processes=12"
      - "-c"
      - "max_parallel_workers_per_gather=6"
      - "-c"
      - "max_parallel_workers=12"

I didn't actually find the reason, but at least I found the cause.
https://github.com/launchbadge/sqlx/issues/2436
https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/1btdrc1/does_sqlx_really_have_more_overhead_in_rust_than/
EDIT2
As the idea was to implement the system in Rust, and libraries such as SQLX and ORM have reduced performance, I chose to use Tokio-Postgres + bb8. In the tests carried out, I simulated 6,000 users per second and it performed well.
let pg_config = Config::from_str("postgresql://postgres:password@localhost/payment_system")?;
let pg_manager = PostgresConnectionManager::new(pg_config, NoTls);

let pg_pool: PosgressPool = Pool::builder().max_size(300).build(pg_manager).await?;

let app: Router = Router::new()
.route("/users/:user_id", get(test).with_state(pg_pool));

_
async fn test(State(pool): State<PosgressPool>, Path(user_id): Path<String>) -> Response {
    let conn = pool.get().await.map_err(internal_error)?;

    let row = conn
        .query_one("SELECT * FROM users WHERE cpf=$1", &[&user_id])
        .await
        .map_err(internal_error)?;

    let user: User = User::from_one(&row);

    Ok((StatusCode::OK, Json(user)).into_response())
}



Repository:
https://github.com/ricardosc12/postgres_rust
